# How to create table in opencart 3.x through ocmod?

Tags: opencart-3, ocmod

I've managed to make an extension for cashback feature in my opencart 3.0.3.2 .I've added the sql for creating a table in model , which i've executed(refer code please) through `install()` from controller.But in the front end while testing it says the table is not created. Please check and tell if I need any other additional requirements to be met. I've attached the code below.

```php
<?php
model
  class ModelExtensionCmsCashback extends Model {
    public function install() {
      $this->db->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" . DB_PREFIX . "product_cashback` ( `cashback_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `product_id` INT NULL , `status` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' , PRIMARY KEY (`cashback_id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;");

  }

  public function uninstall() {
    $this->db->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `" . DB_PREFIX . "product_cashback`");

}

}


<?php
  class ControllerExtensionModuleCashback extends Controller {
    private $error = array();

    public function index() {}

    public function validate() {}

    public function install() {
      $this->load->model('extension/cms/cashback');
      $this->model_extension_cms_cashback->install();
    }

    public function uninstall() {
      $this->load->model('extension/cms/cashback');
      $this->model_extension_cms_cashback->uninstall();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Seems that you have too much `}` in your model. Could you also be more specific about "*The problem I'm facing is regarding the table alteration for adding a column*" - what happens? what did you expect to happen? is there any error?

Comment: @barbsan sorry, i've made the change. Can you help me through this problem?

Comment: You've previously manually deleted the table, right? I know it should be obvious, but we sometimes omit those little mistakes and make a world about the functions, while the solution was always something simple.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install those queries from extension>>modules and search in module section CmsCashback and press the plus sign (install button) next to it. It will execute sql queries and to run uninstall press minus sign